# Not able to implement Temoporal fusion transformer

Tags: time-series, forecasting, pytorch-forecasting

I am trying to solve the following kaggle dataset by using temporal fusion transformer from pytorch_forecasting module but i dont know how to proceed.this is the dataset link:https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/robikscube/hourly-energy-consumption.it will be helful if someone tell me the sample solution and how to approach it.
error im facing currently is in the trainer.fit method:`model` must be a `LightningModule` or `torch._dynamo.OptimizedModule`, got `TemporalFusionTransformer`.It will be helpful if someones gives me full code or just tell how to resolve error

Comment: A reference implementation on a demand forecasting use-case can be found in the official website [here](https://pytorch-forecasting.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/stallion.html).